# script to run mysql commands on all the remote server

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have an script which is running that is taking the server ip from user and running on the server.
but i want the script to read server ip from a file and execute for all the ip mentioned in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so what tools do you have available? Is `ssh` and something like Python, Ruby or Perl an option?

You can do this with `bash` but it tends to get a little messy if you're not familiar with how to script that. You might consider an automation tool to serve as a basis for this before you create some `awk`, `sed` and duct-tape abomination you can't maintain.

Two examples:

- [Capisrano](http://capistranorb.com/) (Ruby)
- [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) (Python)